# Why this elements not coming in centre in mobile version?What is wrong in html or css?

Tags: css, html

I have attached screenshots of desktop & mobile version

I have attached 2 difference screenshots - one desktop & one mobile version (iPhone 6)

How to make the code work similar across all devices?

[image: mobile view]

[image: desktop view]

Why the card is not coming in center in the mobile view, I just a beginner & I am trying to implement a car booking app using Ionic, Angular, HTML, CSS.

Also a little space is wasted on the left - see the screenshots.

My code is

```
 <center>
    <div style="margin-top:80%;width:100%;position:absolute;" class="card">
    <div style="background-color:#002b45;height: 200px;" class="item item-avatar">

  <!-- <div align="center"> -->

   <div class="bottom" style="color: #b4ccda">
   <img style="height:60px;width:120px;border-radius:50%;" class="img_car"    src="assets/images/car1.png">
    <br>Honda City
    <br>HK 1234 5678

      </div>


        <br>
    <button style="width:250px;margin-top:-15px;" class="button button-    positive">
    Book Car
</button>
</div>
</center>
```

Please suggest what is wrong.I want single solution for desktop & mobile

Comment: Post a minimal code snippet reproducing the issue. And the `<center>` tag have been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**[image: CSS]**

***Phone***

```
user-select: none;
    max-width: 3600px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
```

***desktop***

```
width: auto;
    margin: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height: auto;
```

**Edit**

**---------------------------------------------------**

for both

```
width: auto;
    margin: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height: auto;
```

**OR use media query**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    img{
       user-select: none;
       max-width: 3600px;
       margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       left: 50%;
       transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    img{
       user-select: none;
       max-width: 3600px;
       margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       left: 50%;
       transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
    }
}
```

Yes you can add the code inside the css file but change the class name 
to read more about media query look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Comment: I want single solution for desktop & mobile version.

Comment: how to use media query ? can I just add the code in the css file ?

Answer (score 0):

On the first `div`, place it on style: `left:0`
like this

```
<center>
    <div style="left: 0;margin-top:80%;width:100%;position:absolute;" class="card"> ... `
```